# JavaScript - adding prototype(s) to a specific object

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype

So i've been stuck for a couple of days trying to figure out the best practice of implementing the following function into my project:

```
function addClass(myElem, myClass)
{
    if (typeof myElem != "undefined" && myElem && myElem.nodeType === 1 && myClass)
    {
        myClass = (typeof myClass == "string" ? myClass.trim().replace(/[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').split(", ").join(",").split(",").join(" ").split(" ") : myClass);

        for (var i = 0; i < myClass.length; i++)
        {
                myClass[i] = myClass[i].trim();
            if (myClass[i].length > 0 && hasClass(myElem, [myClass[i]], true) === false)
            {
                myElem.className += " " + myClass[i];
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function basically has the same behavior as jQuerys **$.addClass** prototype / function, but has *(at the moment)* no support for inline calling (like the inbuilt functions: ***.trim()*, *.toLowerCase()***, etc etc).

I've read that extending / adding prototypes to an object, isn't really considered good practice and must be avoided if you care about performance *(which I do)*. But as you noticed.. my knowledge about prototypes isn't that great, so any suggestions / answers are more then welcome!

**In Short:**
Basically I want to implement this function, and be callable like this: *document.body.addClass("classToBeAdded");*

Comment: If this code works, but could be improved, it's offtopic here. This should be in Code Review to have people look over your working code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This is about implementation.. not reviewing. I'm trying to figure out how to bind this function as a prototype to objects (so I can call them like I mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that extending / adding prototypes to an object, isn't really considered good practice

It's a matter of opinion, but it does raise the likelihood of conflicts (e.g., two different scripts both adding the same method to a prototype).

> and must be avoided if you care about performance (which I do).

No, adding things to a prototype object doesn't have any significant performance impact; *replacing* the prototype of an object once the object is created does, but you don't need to do that.

> Basically I want to implement this function, and be callable like this: document.body.addClass("classToBeAdded");

You can add it to `HTMLElement.prototype`:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "addClass", {
    value: function() {
        // ...your code here...
    }
});
```

That works on all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Example:

```js
// The extension
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "addClass", {
  value: function(cls) {
    // Not using classList on the assumption that addClass would be unnecessary
    // if the browser supported classList :-)
    this.className += " " + cls;
  }
});

// Using it
document.body.addClass("foo");
document.getElementById("test").addClass("bar");
```

```css
.foo {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bar {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="test">This is a test</p>
```

Comment: You sir.. are a genius! Thanks for your time, and to come back on the quoted senteces. I've read that adding a prototype can cause conflicts in optimization. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @Bilal075_: That's talking about *replacing* the prototype of an existing object, not adding to an existing prototype object.

Comment: Damn.. misreaded. Thank you for your time, I will accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: Extending native prototypes might still lead to unexpected side effects, e.g. when a third-party scripts loops through the prototype properties, for example. And your code might break future web standards if a function with the same name is ever added to that prototype in a standard. Both unlikely scenarios, I know, but still important to keep in mind.

Comment: @nils **addClass** was a 'big' example. I always use vendors / prefixes for my naming. So in this case it would be *strixAddClass*. Would that still risk having conflicts? Smaller chance I guess?

Comment: That would indeed be a lower risk for clashes. If someone (for whatever reason) were to loop through the `HTMLElement.prototype` and the property were enumerable (which it is not in this answer), it might cause some sort of issue. Very hypothetical, I know :D

Comment: @nils: If they try *really* hard, they can enumerable non-enumerable properties, too! :-) (Well, okay, it's not actually all that hard, you just have to go out of your way: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLElement.prototype)`.)

Comment: I know, I know, it's not very likely to happen. Adding an enumerable property to `Object.prototype` would be much worse. The next step after that would probably be Symbols, which can *still* be enumerated. If you want to be sure that it will never be enumerated, you could use a proxy instead ;)

Comment: @nils ;-) Yeah, we have stern words with people doing `Object.prototype.foo = ...`